# CSV file into built in array in stack layout d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, d3.js

I am trying to build a stack bar chart using d3.js. Found great tutorial. But in the example that author uses there is a csv file. I want instead of it to use a built in array of data, but I absolutely don't understand how the code will change when doing stack layout with nesting. Here is a source http://curran.github.io/screencasts/splittingCharts/examples/viewer/#/17 .  I will appreciate it if somebody helps me.
i would like something like this:

```
var arrayOfData ...;
...
function render(data)
{
...
}
...
render(arrayOfData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/uu4p99bf/

```
function render(data){
    var nested = d3.nest(data)//change in here
    //same code with sample
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you can essentially replace `d3.csv('file.csv',render)` with `render(data)`; you'd just need to format your data correctly.

By default [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) loads data as an array of objects, with properties corresponding to each column heading. So in your example, the csv data is loaded in as an array of objects with `.country`, `.religion`, and `.population` properties (e.g. `{country: "USA", religion: "Other Religions", population: 1900000}`). If you get your data into that format, it should work.

Alternatively, you can change the code to reflect the data format that you're currently using. In those cases you'd have to replace instances of where `d[xColumn]`, `d[yColumn]`, and `d[layerColumn]` with what you want. For instance if you're using an array of arrays, they'd become something like `d[0]`, `d[2]`, and `d[1]` respectively.

You may also want to check out the screencast of the example that you're using, which goes more into detail of how it was constructed. You can find via https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/splittingCharts.